# How to get a particular text form a string in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jquery-ui

How to extract a particular value form a textbox (string) and put it into another text box using j-query.

assume that string- in textbox1

```
<input type="text" id="full-name" value="HYDERABAD DECAN [HYB]">

HYDERABAD DECAN [HYB]
```

I Want get as:

```
<input type="text" id="code-name" value="HYB">
```

Get value from textbox1 which under '[......]' i.e HYB and set value on textbox2 value 'HYB'

How to

Comment: If full-name value ="HYDERABAD" then code-name value="HYDERABAD". How to add this check? I have used code already : $('#code-name').val($('#full-name').val().split("[")[1].split("]")[0]); later I want to add this condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
 var fname= $('#full-name').val();
 var word = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
 var wordarr=[]
 for(m = word.exec(fname); m; m = word.exec(fname)){
    wordarr.push(m[1])
 }
 $('#code-name').val(wordarr.join(','));
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Why you need `.*?`. I think `.*` is enough. Isn't it ?

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu: because that will not work in case of multiple square braces.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = "HYDERABAD DECAN [HYB]".match(/\[(.*)\]/);

if (result) {
    alert(result[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var val1=$("#full-name").val();
var val2=val1.substring(val.lastIndexOf("[")+1,val.lastIndexOf("]"));
$("#code-name").val(val2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well one more alternative:

```js
$("#full-name").on("blur",function(){

  
    if($(this).val()!="") //since user has to select from autocomplete dropdown I assume either there will be always a valid text or empty text
    {
       if($(this).val().split("[").length<2)
       {
           $("#code-name").val($(this).val());

        }
       else
       {
        $("#code-name").val($(this).val().split("[")[1].split("]")[0]);
       }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="full-name" value="HYDERABAD DECAN [HYB]">
<input type="text" id="code-name">
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7buykteL/)**

Comment: I want to put value in #code-name when #full-name value is changed@Guruprasad

Comment: and how your `#full-name` value gets changed. By user input or some other way??

Comment: Yeah ! #full-name value load from a ajax autocomplete list box. After typing some text it will show a full name list, if user click on any of them the selected text is insert on #full-name. and I want to extract value under [....] to #code-name value. i think u understand. If possible to execute your code on #full-name on change event...then help me @G.Rao

Comment: I have edited the answer.. use `blur` event of textbox.

Comment: One more thing in this ?  @Mr. Rao

Comment: If full-name value ="HYDERABAD" then code-name value="HYDERABAD". How to add this check? I have used code already : $('#code-name').val($('#full-name').val().split("[")[1].split("]")[0]); later I want to add this condition.

Comment: i.e full-name value contains text with [....] then your code. or if full-name value not contains [....] then  full-name and code-name same text .

Comment: Right now I cannot answer properly.. because I cannot test since I am replying in mobile. Will give u proper solution tomorrow morning...

Comment: There you go @BikashMahata.. It's working now. Mark it as answer if it helped you..